# Display ratio as decimal between two PHP variables

Tags: mysql, function, phpunit

I log stats for my Minecraft server and display player's in-game stats on my site. I log kills and deaths already, but now I'm trying to get a functioning kill/death ratio.

I am trying to display the kills/deaths in a decimal ratio format (Example: 3789 kills - 5711 deaths would give you a K/DR of 0.663)

```
elseif ($_GET['task'] == 'stats') {
        $get_player = $_GET['player'];
        $get_db = 'engine';
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $get_db WHERE name = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($get_player) . "'", $link);
            while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo '{"task":"viewstats","kills":"'; echo $data['kills'];
                                echo '","deaths":"'; echo $data['deaths'];
                                echo '","joins":"'; echo $data['joins'];
                                echo '","quits":"'; echo $data['quits'];
                                echo '","kicked":"'; echo $data['kicked'];
                echo '"}';
            }
    }
```

I call upon them in a table like this:

```
<td><?php echo empty($stats) ? "--" : substr($stats->kills, 0, 50); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo empty($stats) ? "--" : substr($stats->deaths, 0, 50); ?></td>
```

The above PHP code is an API file and the MySQL is already enabled in it - I only posted a snippet of the API though.

Comment: It looks like you're forming JSON with this. You should really do that with [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) by first constructing an array then encoding it.

Comment: Does `$data['kills'] / $data['deaths']` not give you the value you need?

Comment: Use `number_format()` to display the desired number of decimal places. http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'task' => 'viewstats',
    'kills' => $data['kills'],
    'deaths' => $data['deaths'],
    'joins'=> $data['joins'],
    'quits' => $data['quits'],
    'kicked' => $data['kicked'],

    // then ratio
    'ratio' => $data['kills'] / $data['deaths'],
));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//**Make sure this Function is declared at the top of your script.**
function MySQLi_quickConnect()
{
  $host     = 'somewebsite.db.120327161.hostedresource.com'; //or 'http://localhost'
  $username = '<YOUR USERNAME>';
  $password = '<YOUR PASSWORD>';
  $database = '<YOUR DATABASES NAME>';

  $db = new MySQLi($host,$username,$password,$database);
  $error_message = $db->connect_error;
  if($error_message != NULL){die("Error:" . $error_message . "<br>" . "Occured in function
                                         MySQLi_quickConnect");}
  return $db;   
}

//Replace your code with this: 

 elseif($_GET['task'] == 'stats') {
 $get_player = $_GET['player'];
 $get_db = 'engine';

 $mysqli = MySQLi_quickConnect();
 $query  = ('SELECT kills, deaths, FROM ? WHERE name = ? ');
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $get_db, $get_player);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($kills, $deaths);
 }
 while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $kdr = $kills/$deaths;
  echo "You have a  K/DR of " . $kdr . "<br>";
 }

 $stmt->close();
}
```

Note: Verify your Database connection, table names, and $_Get variables.